# Regex pattern to get numbers from string

Tags: regex, shell

I have a string as below :

```
30750 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task  - Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
```

Now I want to extract the numbers from it and add them up using shell script. Basically I want to get the sum of number of mappers and reducers. Splitting the string based on 'space character' does seem to be working for me, any regex pattern will do the stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your Q to show  your expected output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne '$s+=$1 foreach /number of .*?: (\d+)/g; print $s'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/8ghKE5

---

An awk version:

```
awk '{while(match($0,"number of [^:]+: ([[:digit:]]+)",a)){s+=a[1];$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}END{print s}'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Hbccm9

Explanation:

- The `while()` loop sums up all numbers into variable `s` extracted with the help of the regex in `match()`.

  - In the loop condition:

    - The `match()` function tries to find the pattern `number of [^:]+: ([[:digit:]]+)` in the current input string (`$0`) and stores capture groups (subpatterns in parenthesis - `([[:digit:]]+)` in our case) in the array `a`.
    - The regex `number of [^:]+: ([[:digit:]]+)` matches substring `"number of <something not containing ':'>: <sequence of digits>"` and captures the `<sequence of digits>` (which is effectively a number we're looking for) into the capture group one.
  - In the loop body:

    - `s+=a[1]` adds to `s` the number which was captured in the group one by the regex in `match()`
    - `$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)` removes from the input string `$0` everything up to (and including) substring matched the pattern in the `match()` so that this `match()` would lookup further on the next iteration.
- The finalization block (`END{...}`) just prints the sum collected in `s`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, can you explain the thing that you have shared for 'awk'

Comment: @MohitRane, You're welcome! I've added explanation to the answer.

Comment: Can you please help with the regex pattern to get 'date and time ' out of below string.
     '30807 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task  - 2016-08-11 06:41:08,318 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%' 

Output should contain : 2016-08-11 06:41:08
I just want to get the time when the mapper and reducer are launched.
Thanks

Comment: It's [`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/pA8uD8/1) in PCRE flavour.

Comment: Its in pearl, I need it to be in shell script.

Comment: The PCRE is a library which is utilized by a number of tools to provide Perl compatible syntax. So you're not necessarily bound to Perl. You can use it with grep, for instance: https://ideone.com/lJcyqa. I used this flavour for it's more concise comparing to POSIX one.

Comment: Cool, Thanks.
So that means I have to use the syntax as it is, because when I am putting echo statement and grep statement in single line its not working.
Am I right ?
Can you explain this one also

Comment: You may put it into one: https://ideone.com/t1iA0p. I split it just for clarity. If it does not work, I suggest to check the quotes and parameters and then environment (what exactly shell are you using? shell and grep versions?). What is the exact line you tried?

Comment: Thanks a ton @Dmitry.
It worked exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121041/discussion-between-dmitry-egorov-and-mohit-rane).